# Is quadratic dependence of kinetic energy on velocity a consequence of time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy

Could we say that the quadratic dependence of velocity compensates for the fact that clocks run slower when velocity increases?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: kinetic energy depends quadratically on velocity in _classical_ mechanics, while time dilation is a _relativistic_ effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. But I'm kind of curious: what line of reasoning led you to that conjecture???

Here's maybe a better way of intuitively seeing the $v^2$ dependence of kinetic energy. Suppose you're immersed in an environment containing identical small particles of mass $m$, uniformly distributed everywhere. Now you start moving through the particles with velocity $v$ such that each collision imparts momentum $mv$, and in time interval $\Delta t$ you collide with $n$ particles.

Now you double your speed to $2v$. So now each collision imparts double the momentum, $2mv$. **Moreover** (and here's where the $v^2$ comes in), in that same time interval $\Delta t$ you now collide with $2n$ particles. So when you double your speed, you collide with double the number of particles and each collision imparts double the momentum. And that's how you get $2\times2=4$.

Comment: That's an explanation for the quadratic dependence of drag on velocity, not the quadratic dependence of kinetic energy on velocity.

Comment: @JohnRennie six-of-one, half-a-dozen of the other, more or less. Just flip the situation. I described perfectly inelastic collisions, with the big mass, call it $M$, acquiring all the momentum (as you say, in a retarding sense) from the little $m$'s. If perfectly elastic instead, and $M>>m$, you'd have to account for the fact that the little $m$'s "bounce" off $M$ at twice $M$'s speed, etc. But the overall "square" idea would work out the same, with big $M$'s drag now interpreted as all the little $m$'s gains. Pretty much just a change of reference frame (along with elastic<-->inelastic).